# Homebrew (mac) : Reinstallation failure

Tags: macos, homebrew

Ok so I was having problems with homebrew where it would give me an error when I use any brew command, so I decided to reinstall homebrew. I used the most standard uninstallation commands you see on the internet.
After checking the brew command isn't recognized by the console, I installed homebrew again.

This is what happened.

```
localhost:~ ~~~~~~~~$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Library/Caches/Homebrew
Password:
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 199994, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54010/54010), done.
remote: Total 199994 (delta 144802), reused 199994 (delta 144802)
Receiving objects: 100% (199994/199994), 41.97 MiB | 187.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (144802/144802), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
HEAD is now at 5057268 ledger: update 3.0.3_1 bottle.
-e:196:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from -e:196:in `<main>'
```

When I execute "brew", this is what is says.

```
localhost:~ ~~~~~~~~$ brew
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:105:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:105:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

It would be very nice if any of you could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was because I had [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#understanding-path) installed but hadn't added the paths to my `$PATH` environment variable.

If you use **bash** then try the following:

- Add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your `~/.bash_profile`.
- Check that `~/.rbenv/bin` and `~/.rbenv/shims` are in your `$PATH` by running `echo $PATH`

If you use **[Fish Shell](http://fishshell.com/)** then you need to load rbenv in a different way. Add the following 3 lines to your `~/.config/fish/fish.config` file:

```
set PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin $PATH
set PATH $HOME/.rbenv/shims $PATH
rbenv rehash >/dev/null ^&1
```